# How can I restore one file from my crashed bacula system

Tags: 12.04

How can I restore one file from my crashed bacula system.I just want to restore one of the file that are in my bacula system that  crashed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you have a volumes with your backups available? If yes, use a bextract utility for that.